# Fast way to search words in big array of object | NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, search

I have an array of 10K objects, include title, content and more.
I want to search words in the array and filter the objects that contain the words.
I am looking for a technology to do it much faster then the naive approach of looping the array.
Using NodeJs and TypeScript.

Comment: Maybe use a database instead? Databases are built for doing this sort of thing quickly. A more general scripting language, probably not so much.